# Activating the has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, bcrypt

I am trying to activate rails has_secure_password in my User model.

I have installed the brypt gem: **gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'**

My model is as follows

```
#Schema: User(name:string, password_digest:string)

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
  validates_confirmation_of :password
end
```

When I run the following commands in the rails sandbox I get (using rails 4.1.0):

```
user = User.new(name:'tbtb', password: 'tbtb', pasword_confirmation: 'tbtb')
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: pasword_confirmation
```

and

```
user = User.new(name:'tbtb', password_digest: 'tbtb')
<User id: nil, name: "tbtb", password_digest: "tbtb", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Which is as expected if you are not using the has_secure_password. It almost seems as if the has_secure_password is not being activated and the password_digest field is not being interpreted by ActiveRecord (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html)

Can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: `pasword_confirmation` with one S?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple typo, change `pasword_confirmation` to `password_confirmation`:

```
user = User.new(name:'tbtb', password: 'tbtb', password_confirmation: 'tbtb')
```

Comment: Hah, this is true. Thank you